# Google Map V2 disable MyLocation blue icon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

When i setLocationSource, Google Map will display the blue icon automatically. Anyone know how to remove the blue icon??

Thanks.

[Something like that](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/78582670/20130327_133518.jpg)

There is my coding:

```
 private Marker myLocation = null;

private void prepareMapSetting(GoogleMap aGoogleMap)
{
    aGoogleMap.setLocationSource(mLocationSource);
    aGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(mOnMyLocationChangeListener);
    aGoogleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(mOnMapLongClickListener);
        aGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}


private OnMapLongClickListener mOnMapLongClickListener = new OnMapLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point)
    {
        if(null != mOnLocationChangedListener){
            if(null == myLocation){
                myLocation = getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title("You")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            }
            else{
                myLocation.setPosition(point);
            }

            Location location = new Location("LongPressLocationProvider");
            location.setLatitude(point.latitude);
            location.setLongitude(point.longitude);
            mOnLocationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }


    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question (I don't see your image too).

In fact `setLocationSource` is just to set the location source of the mylocation layer (i.e.,  the blue dot...)

if you don't want the blue dot, just put

```
  aGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

and don't use the locationSource